# is it possible to open custom popup when click on copy link on instagram in swift

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I  develop an app in which I open Instagram in wkwebview and I want to open popup when a user taps on the copy link by tapping on three dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this code in view did load-:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(clipboardChanged),
                                           name: UIPasteboard.changedNotification, object: nil)
```

And further, if you want to open popup in your clipboard in this event -:

```
@objc func clipboardChanged(){
    let pasteboardString: String? = UIPasteboard.general.string
    if let theString = pasteboardString {
        print("String is \(theString)")
       
          // Open your view controller here 
        
    }
}
```